# How to set fixed size form to different resolutions

Tags: c#, winforms, screen, resolution, formborderstyle

I have a problem and I couldn't find the answer anywhere on the internet. I am working on a project which its forms should be fixedsingle borderstyle. I don't want anyone to maximize or minimize the forms. So the real question is that I have two monitors and I'm working on the bigger one. When I start the program and slide the form to the smaller monitor, it looks exactly the same heigth and width. But I want the form to look smaller as the screen gets small or to look bigger if the screen gets bigger. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [Form.MinimumSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize?view=netframework-4.8) and [Form.MaximumSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize?view=netframework-4.8) properties according to your needs. If you want to adjust the form dynamically at run time, you can hook the [Form.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.move?view=netframework-4.8) event and set those properties relative to the screen's resolution minus the space used by the taskbar using [Screen.WorkingArea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea?view=netframework-4.8). For a better user experience if the form is smaller than the screen size, I recommend disabling the maximize form button by setting [Form.MaximizeBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.maximizebox?view=netframework-4.8) to false.